# Why is my form being wrongly validated?

Tags: php

I'm sure this get's asked a lot but everybody's code is different, but I'm having trouble validating my registration form.

I'll post my code below the snippet.

Now what exactly am I doing wrong? I want to make sure every field is filled out but even if I use the code below or I add in a die() function with an error echo the rest of the code still gets executed and the form is sent off.

The snippet below is the sort of thing I've been trying.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
if(empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($username) || empty($password) || 
empty($passwordconf) 
{
echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
die();  
}   
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
```

This is my current code as it stands.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$username = "DBname";
$password = "DBpass";
$hostname = "DBhost"; 
$md5pass = md5($pass);


if(empty($email)){ //this is what I've tried 
    $errors[] = "email cannot be left empty";
}

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to server");

$con=mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
$select=mysql_select_db("Database", $con) or die("cannot select DB");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows==0)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO login(username,password,firstname,lastname,email) 
VALUES('$user','$md5pass','$fname','$lname','$email')";

$result=mysql_query($sql);


if($result){
echo "Account Successfully Created, Please login to continue";
} else {
echo "Failure!";
}

} else {
echo "That username already exists! Please try again with another.";
}
}
```

Comment: Your database is very vulnerable to injection

Comment: **Danger**: You are mixing [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) with a modern one (which won't work) and should use only a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: It isn't erroring, because the code you say you are using, doesn't have the `die` statement in it.

Comment: Yes I know my code probably isn't safe but this site isn't actually live. 
I'm trying to learn everything before I put it into actual practise

Comment: I see this response all the time.  Why wouldn't you want to learn and practice the correct way!?

Comment: I am doing it the correct way! just not in this project :) 
I'm sorry but I just want to know how to properly validate my form, I'm well aware of the issues already there.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(empty($_POST['fname'])||..`. You are checking a variable `$firstname` in the first part that isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it got lost during copy but the second if needs a closing **)**

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($passwordconf)) {
```